# Could't have permission to view the PDF (preview)

Tags: pdftex

I am using mac, preview to check the PDFLaTeX files under the Texmaker.

[image]

[The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.]

To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

But I can read and write.

What' t the wrong? Thank you very much!

I have check the preview again, But I still couldn't find the place where to change. Is it in the Services?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please verify your permissions concerning the parent folder of your pdf document? Where is your *.tex and your generated *.pdf located?

Comment: I have checked the preview again, But I still couldn't find the place where to change. Is it in the Services? Thank you!

Comment: Where is your pdf file located? Is it in a subdirectory of your home folder? Are you able to view the pdf by opening it through the finder?